# Splitting a Cell String to Create two rows using the parts

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset with a format approximately like the following:

.../DATA/...
Cats/1763/9.4+5.6/Happy
.../DATA/...

What I am looking to do is seatch down the column with the concatenated numbers and separate each of them; 9.4 and 5.6 and create two rows next to each other with all other data the same:

.../DATA/...
Cats/1763/9.4/Happy
Cats/1763/5.6/Happy
.../DATA/...

Going through a few thousand rows not all  of which are concatenated.

I have made some attempts but although the individual components seem to work (in the sense of not throwing up syntax errors) the whole doesnt. Any Ideas?

The main function is 'plusinsert' which takes a string from a drop down table to target a specific worksheet. Its cobbled together from various forum snippets, wish I could credit the original authors but I didnt get the names.

```
Sub CopyR()
Dim cl As Range
Dim r As Long
Set cl = ActiveCell
r = cl.Row
Range("a" & r, Range("CQ" & r)).Copy

End Sub  


Function Extractparts(path As String)
Dim parts

parts = Split(path, "+")
Extract1 = parts(1)
Extract2 = parts(2)
End Function  
Public Sub plusinsert(name As String)

Dim Target2, cell As Range
Dim cellvalue As String

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(name).Activate
Set Target2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("G1"), Range("D65536").End(xlUp))

For Each cell In Target2
If cell.CountIf(cell, "*+*") Then
cellvalue = cell.Value:
Extractparts (cellvalue):
CopyR:
ActiveSheet.Paste:
Application.CutCopyMode = False:
cell.Value = Extract1:
cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Extract2
Next cell

End Sub
```

With the Data in columns I solved this using the following code:

```
Dim Target, cell, RowRange As Range
Dim cellvalue As String
Dim Count As Integer
' Snippet target range, is for whole column in production.
Set Target = Range("G2:G8")  

Dim TestArray() As String  

For Each cell In Target
  TestArray() = Split(cell.Value, "+"):
  cell.Value = TestArray(0)
  If UBound(TestArray) > 0 Then
  Set RowRange = cell.EntireRow:
  RowRange.Copy:
  RowRange.Insert Shift:=xlUp:
  Application.CutCopyMode = False:
  cell.Value = TestArray(1)
End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Show us the code of your attempts.

Comment: screenshot would help too

Comment: Before looking at coding, have you tried to use Excels [Data] / [Text to Columns] feature to split up data rows into different cells (setting delimiters to "/" and then to "+"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note*** » the commented out section where you can adjust your `Column`, `firstDataRow`, `deli` and `delim` settings

Assuming your data is all placed in column `A` ; your sheet looks like this: 
[image: start]

you run this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitingAndInserting()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim i&, deli$, delim$, urColumn$, firstDataRow&

    ' setters
    ' modify them if you need to
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    urColumn = "A"
    firstDataRow = 1
    deli = "+"
    delim = "/"

    For i = ws.Range(urColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To firstDataRow Step -1
        Set rng = ws.Range(urColumn & i)
        If InStr(1, rng.Value, deli, vbTextCompare) Then
            Dim var As Variant
            var = Split(rng.Value, deli)
            If UBound(var) > 0 Then
                ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Dim j&
                Dim fpart As String
                fpart = var(0)
                Dim spart As String
                spart = var(1)
                For j = 1 To Len(spart)
                    If StrComp(delim, Left(Right(spart, j), 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        fpart = fpart + Right(spart, j)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                rng = fpart
                fpart = var(0)
                For j = 1 To Len(fpart)
                    If StrComp(delim, Left(Right(fpart, j), 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        spart = Left(fpart, Len(fpart) - (j - 1)) & spart
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                rng.Offset(1, 0) = spart
            End If
        End If
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```

to get results like these: 
[image: finish]

Comment: Thanks for the help, if my rep was high enough I would give you a  useful upvote.

Comment: @user2539485 you can still accept the answer :) below the up vote there is a green check mark